# MVC: Get JSON data from a controller using AJAX failed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to query data using AJAX from a controller, my controller is:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetTestStatus(string userName)
{
    var db = new SREvalEntities();
    var allTests = db.Tests
        .Where(x => string.Equals(x.Owner, userName))
        .Select(x => new { CreateDate = x.CreateDate, EndDate = x.EndDate, Status = x.Status })
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreateDate)
        .ToList();

    return Json(allTests, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And my javascript code in an extern file is:

```
function Filter() {
    var userAlias = document.getElementById("UserAliasInput");
    var txt = "<tr><th>StartDate</th><th>EndDate</th><th>Status</th><th>Detail</th></tr>";
    $.ajax({
        url: '/TestStatus/GetTestStatus',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: { userName: userAlias },
        success: function (results) {
            $.each(results, function (i, result) {
                txt += "<tr><td>" + result.CreateDate + "</td>";
                txt += "<td>" + result.EndDate + "</td>";
                txt += "<td>" + result.Status + "</td>";
                txt += "<td><a href=\"\">Goto</a></td></tr>";
            });
        }
    });
    $("#ShowDetail").html(txt);
}
```

When I tried to debug this function, the code will never excute to

```
$("#ShowDetail").html(txt);
```

And my page will never be changed. How can I get it work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `$.ajax()`, which is asynchronous. Thus the `$("#ShowDetail").html(txt)` is called before the value is returned from API.

You should set the `html()` after the each block

```
function Filter() {
    var userAlias = document.getElementById("UserAliasInput");
    var txt = "<tr><th>StartDate</th><th>EndDate</th><th>Status</th><th>Detail</th></tr>";
    $.ajax({
        url: '/TestStatus/GetTestStatus',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: { userName: userAlias.value }, //Use the value property here
        success: function (results) {
            $.each(results, function (i, result) {
                txt += "<tr><td>" + result.CreateDate + "</td>";
                txt += "<td>" + result.EndDate + "</td>";
                txt += "<td>" + result.Status + "</td>";
                txt += "<td><a href=\"\">Goto</a></td></tr>";
            });

            $("#ShowDetail").html(txt); //Move code to set text here
        }
    });    
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I do as what you said but it doesn't work. I add `alert(results);` in success callback and the page gives no response. By typing /TestStatus/GetTestStaus?userName=... I can see the JSON returned by the controller.

Comment: @OnceJune, Use `{ userName: userAlias.value }`

Comment: sorry to bother you again. Since '$.ajax()' is asynchronous, how can I do something after '$.ajax()' returned in the same function? Such as update the page? Thank you.

Comment: @OnceJune, Yes you can

Answer (score 0):

Try the following function

```
function Filter() {
    var userAlias = $("#UserAliasInput").val();//change this
    var txt = "<tr><th>StartDate</th><th>EndDate</th><th>Status</th><th>Detail</th></tr>";
    $.ajax({
        url: '/TestStatus/GetTestStatus',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: { userName: userAlias },
        success: function (results) {
            $.each(results, function (i, result) {
                txt += "<tr><td>" + result.CreateDate + "</td>";
                txt += "<td>" + result.EndDate + "</td>";
                txt += "<td>" + result.Status + "</td>";
                txt += "<td><a href=\"\">Goto</a></td></tr>";
            });
            $("#ShowDetail").html(txt);//place this in the success function
        }
    });
}
```